# Disable Radio buttons active style with jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, radio-button

How to disable the change of style when clicking on radio button? On click event adds **.ui-btn-active** to the style (delete this from css is not a solution)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override the jQuery Mobile CSS, simple as that.  jQuery Mobile appends a lot of classes on the fly so it may take you a while to track all of the selectors down and modify them.